# Can i calculate exp(1+2j) in python?

Tags: python, math

Can i calculate exp(1+2j) in python?

```
exp(1+2j)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't convert complex to float
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need a complex version of this function:

```
cmath.exp(1+2j)
```

See http://docs.python.org/library/cmath.html

Comment: Would disagree with the word "need" in this case. I do use the cmath package, but in this simple case: e**(1+2j) = e**(1) * e**(2j) = e * ( cos(2) + sin(2)j )

Answer (score 18):

You may want to import `e` from the math module to do this.

For example:

```
>>> from math import e
>>> print e ** (1+2j)
(-1.1312043837568135+2.4717266720048188j)
```

Comment: interesting that this works but `math.exp(1+2j)` does not.