# how to add phases(complex number array) into each elements(floats) in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Recently I work on diffraction pattern, I wanna add phases into amplitudes which are float numbers. I use this code.

```
A=np.multiply(math.exp(1j),AA)
```

`AA` is another array with amplitude.
the shell show error and say "can not convert complex to float". How to solve it? please!

Comment: Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498310/can-i-calculate-exp12j-in-python

Comment: @Kasramvd: Not really a duplicate (or at least, not of the linked question).  The problem here is coming from use of the `math` module rather than the `cmath` module.

Comment: Ah yes, that one's a better duplicate.

Comment: To the OP: use `np.exp` rather than `math.exp` or `cmath.exp`!

Comment: @Kasramvd: The problem has nothing to do with arrays.  The error message that the OP sees is coming from the call `math.exp(1j)`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Yep,that's the reason!

Comment: thanks for the correction!!